# Interface segregation principle and single responsibility principle

Tags: solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, interface-segregation-principle

I have an interface with 9 methods each doing something different but in one context. That is, when I use dependency injection on this interface, all 9 methods are used in one specific scope. Should I do 9 different interfaces for all methods and 9 classes to implement these interfaces if I always use all 9 methods after creating an instance?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is meant here by "context" and "scope". The questions to ask are: 1. when a client needs to use this interface, does it need to call all nine methods, or only a subset of them; and 2. when you need to change this interface or its implementations in the future, is a given change likely to affect all nine methods or only a subset of them?

Comment: By context, I mean everything that happens during one http request. By scope, I mean everything that happens during one instance of this interface which can be created per any dependency injection, per request or as singleton. 1: When client needs to use this interface then it can use any method of this interface. 2: Any change in implementation will affect only changed method. Changing any of the 9 methods does not affect the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use all or most of these nine methods in every use case, then it is clear that you do not need interface segregation.

However, the reason you are even asking this is probably that having nine methods appear too much. This may be the case and it sounds like perhaps you need some refactoring, but no one can tell you that without studying your code.